# I tried inserting a document in mongodb but I then,

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, components

I tried inserting a document in mongodb but I then, I received an error saying "Insert not permitted while document contains errors" and yet, I still can't find where the error is in my code,
please help.

I do not know if there's a new version of mongodb or probably a new way of writing code to insert documents in mongodb but still, I've tried all I can to locate the error in this code but I still couldn't.
I also tried checking if I used the curly bracket incorrectly or the square bracket incorrectly but I think its probably fine to me but I'm unsure. Hopefully someone blessed can help me check it out.

````
[ 
  {
    "images": [
        {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/pb8fnxyickqqe9krov82",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605263280/nextjs_media/pb8fnxyickqqe9krov82.jpg"
        },
        {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/irfwxjz56x4xa6pdwoks",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605263281/nextjs_media/irfwxjz56x4xa6pdwoks.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "checked": false,
    "inStock": 500,
    "sold": 0,
    "title": "animal",
    "price": 5,
    "description": "How to and tutorial videos of cool CSS effect, Web Design ideas,JavaScript libraries, Node.",
    "content": "Welcome to our channel Dev AT. Here you can learn web designing, UI/UX designing, html css tutorials, css animations and css effects, javascript and jquery tutorials and related so on.",
    "category": "5faa35a88fdff228384d51d8"
  },
  {
    "images": [
        {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/jdi9qo0oiinwik8uxzxn",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605278590/nextjs_media/jdi9qo0oiinwik8uxzxn.jpg"
         },
         {
           "public_id": "nextjs_media/k2pjwtpzolcieioacnu2",
           "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605278591/nextjs_media/k2pjwtpzolcieioacnu2.jpg"
         },
          {
           "public_id": "nextjs_media/qbh6auephsy5leaapsu1",
           "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605278592/nextjs_media/qbh6auephsy5leaapsu1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "public_id": "nextjs_media/gnsgrxorl5utlnxygjn6",
            "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605278594/nextjs_media/gnsgrxorl5utlnxygjn6.jpg"
           },
            { 
              "public_id": "nextjs_media/w8qj2rlrhh1es8wxhcui",
              "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605278596/nextjs_media/w8qj2rlrhh1es8wxhcui.jpg"
           }
     ],
    "checked": false,
    "inStock": 300,
    "sold": 10,
    "title": "wedding invitation",
    "price": 5,
    "description": "How to and tutorial videos of cool CSS effect, Web Design ideas,JavaScript libraries, Node.",
    "content": "Welcome to our channel Dev AT. Here you can learn web designing, UI/UX designing, html css tutorials, css animations and css effects, javascript and jquery tutorials and related so on.",
    "category": "5faa35b58fdff228384d51da"
  },
  {
    "images": [
       {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/u8qltexka25minj2rj46",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605318879/nextjs_media/u8qltexka25minj2rj46.jpg"
        },
        {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/wb5osprab71emsxp3ibm",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605318910/nextjs_media/wb5osprab71emsxp3ibm.jpg"
        },
        {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/nelvbtwdbk1vjvhufort",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605318911/nextjs_media/nelvbtwdbk1vjvhufort.jpg"
        },
        {
          "public_id": "nextjs_media/bnyeto9vaz40yfts92we",
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/devatchannel/image/upload/v1605318913/nextjs_media/bnyeto9vaz40yfts92we.jpg"
         }
    ],
    "checked": false,
    "inStock": 153,
    "sold": 5,
    "title": "laptop",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "How to and tutorial videos of cool CSS effect, Web Design ideas,JavaScript libraries, Node.",
    "content": "Welcome to our channel Dev AT. Here you can learn web designing, UI/UX designing, html css tutorials, css animations and css effects, javascript and jquery tutorials and related so on.",
    "category": "5faa35a88fdff228384d51d8"
  }
]```
````

Comment: I vote that the inserted document is not valid bson document. Try excluding field by field until the document will be finally able to be inserted

Comment: The 3 documents in the array insert fine with: `db.collection.insertMany( [ ... ] )`

Comment: That array also inserts fine via compass.